# Prevent CSS URL from htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a standard rewrite with `.htaccess` to do this

> `http://www.myurl.com/post/{id}/`

```
RewriteRule    ^post/([0-9]+)/?$    post.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Now, it works perfectly but all others external URL ( for example CSS and JavaScript ) do not work, rightly.
Is there a way to prevent it without having to change all the url ? I searched on Google without success, any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need an additional rule to fix css, js, images links:

```
# your rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# fix css, js, image links
RewriteRule ^post/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Alternatively make sure to just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`

Comment: Or make sure that all your paths are relative to the site root (i.e. include `/css/stylesheet.css` instead of `css/stylesheet.css` in your HTML code).

Answer (score 4):

Simply exclude physical files from your condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^post/([0-9]+)/?$    post.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Good answer, I would definitely change this, but anubhava's answer addresses the real problem.

Comment: That actually won't help if relative css paths is being used and path is becoming for ex. `/post/css/style.css`

Comment: Exactly, it is just the first step for having files accessible.

Comment: i tried in this way but it returns 404 error

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have to access your files by their real path, not using `post/`. If you want something with, refer to anubhava's answer ;) More explainations here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879058/1529139