# Css files are being loaded with no rules on every page except home page

Tags: css, .htaccess, codeigniter

So we have recently tried to host our site on our test Server and for some reason on my local machine all assets load correctly, but on our server the css files load with no rules on each page aside from the home page.

Our site is currently hosted on http://qbtei.com/commercialMaster

On a page like http://qbtei.com/commercialMaster/welcome/about you can see that the css file loads with no rules.

I am sorry I haven't included many examples of the code, the problem is that i am not sure what the cause could be.

We think it might be HtAccess related, but everything we have tried for it has made no difference.

Our Htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am very noob at changing my htaccess file so i used different info i found on the internet. Also its important to note this site is built using codeigniter.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913132/prevent-css-url-from-htaccess-rewrite

Comment: You're calling from the current directory, not a root directory. The difference between `public/files` and `/public/files` is what you're missing.

Comment: I tried adding the / , but it doesnt work. Using the full site path to the css file works, but that seems like a poor solution